# How to add parent attributes inside its children in rabl template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rabl

How to add parent attributes inside its children in rabl template? To do something like this:

```
parent: {
  attr_1: 'asd',
  attr_2: 'dfg',
  child: {
    attr_3: 6,
    attr_from_parent: 'cvb'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
object @parent
attributes :attr_1, :attr_2

child :child do
  attributes :attr_3, :name
  node(:attr_from_parent) { @parent.attr_from_parent }
end
```

You may also have a look at http://railscasts.com/episodes/322-rabl?view=asciicast

Comment: This is not working because |parent| is equal to child. Any other ideas?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is right example, but I oversimplified the question and missed the point. This is my new more exact question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15878381/625521 appreciate your help.