# Accessing parent object in rabl template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, api, rabl

I have a Submission model

```
belongs_to :report
has_many :answers
```

Report Model

```
has_many :questions
```

Question Model

```
has_many :answers   # answer has submission_id
```

Now in rabl template I need output like this

```
        object @submission
        attributes :status, :submission_time

        child :report do
            attribute :id, :name
            child :questions do
                attribute :id, :content
                node(:answers_count) do |question|
                    question.answers.where("submission_id = ?", @submission.id).count
                end
                node(:answers) do |question|
                    question.answers.where("submission_id = ?", @submission.id).collect{ |answer| {:name => answer.name, :id => answer.id}}
                end
            end
        end
```

This is working perfectly fine but the problem is in answers_count and answers node I am using @submission and because of that index action is not working.

Its fine in show action but index action is creating issues as @submission is not available in index action.

*PS: Once I fix the issue I will move the big query from view to model. I know that, Just for simplicity I have pasted that inline.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the best solution but it will work

```
object @submission
attributes :status, :submission_time

child :report do
    attribute :id, :name

    submission_id = locals['submission'] ? locals['submission'].id : locals[:object].id

    child :questions do
        attribute :id, :content
        node(:answers_count) do |question|
            question.answers.where("submission_id = ?", submission_id ).count
        end
        node(:answers) do |question|
            question.answers.where("submission_id = ?", submission_id ).collect{ |answer| {:name => answer.name, :id => answer.id}}
        end

    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you, although it's a bit of a hack admittedly.  I've kept the non-working solutions below for posterity:

```
object @submission
attributes :status, :submission_time

child :report do
    submission_id = root_object.id
    attribute :id, :name
    child :questions do
        attribute :id, :content
        node(:answers_count) do |question|
            question.answers.where("submission_id = ?", submission_id).count
        end
        node(:answers) do |question|
            question.answers.where("submission_id = ?", submission_id).collect{ |answer| {:name => answer.name, :id => answer.id}}
        end
    end
end
```

**INCORRECT SOLUTIONS:**

Use `root_object` for this:

```
node(:answers_count) do |question|
  question.answers.where("submission_id = ?", root_object.id).count
end
```

Alternatively, pass it as an argument to the `child :report` block:

```
    object @submission
    attributes :status, :submission_time

    child :report do |submission|
        attribute :id, :name
        child :questions do
            attribute :id, :content
            node(:answers_count) do |question|
                question.answers.where("submission_id = ?", submission.id).count
            end
            node(:answers) do |question|
                question.answers.where("submission_id = ?", submission.id).collect{ |answer| {:name => answer.name, :id => answer.id}}
            end
        end
    end
```

Unfortunately, neither of these approaches worked. The first solution doesn't work because `root_object` changes with the block scope (it identifies the parent for the containing block).  The second solution doesn't work because unlike `node`, `child` passes in the child object for that iteration.  Unfortunately, this is contrary to what [the documentation](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl#child-nodes) would have you believe.

Comment: In first solution root_object is pointing the question object for that loop and in second solution submission start pointing to report object. :(

Comment: @MohitJain: You are right, but there must be a mistake in [the docs](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl#child-nodes)  that seems to indicate the second solution would work.  Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15878381/how-to-add-parent-attributes-inside-its-children-in-rabl-template-when-parent-i which seems to have a similar problem.  Frankly, I'm surprised that RABL makes it difficult to access the root via child (as opposed to a node).